# Vista and Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, windows-vista, oracle10g, localhost

I am getting this error message in Internet Explorer with Oracle 10g installed on Vista:

The 'oraoledb.oracle.1' provider is not registered on the local machine

I can connect to Oracle databases OK with SQL Server 2008 as a linked database. However, my IE 7 doesn't see it.

I have installed it as administrator and tried many different things. I followed the instructions on the Oracle site on installing Oracle 10g on Vista.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a permissions issue. Your IIS and ASPNET users don't have the required privileges to access the ORACLE_HOME folder.

Right click your ORACLE_HOME folder, choose Properties and go to the tab named Security. Add the 'Users' group (or IIS and ASPNET), and grant them "List Folder Contents", "Read", and "Read and Execute". Hit Apply, then go to Advanced. Check the box saying "Replace permission entries on all child objects" and hit Apply.